# Function from $\mathbb R^{2}$ to $\mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let, $z=x+iy$ and $f:\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb R^{2}$ be the function $f(x,y)=f(z)=z^{2}=(x^{2}-y^{2},2xy). Let $$(Df)(a)$ denotes the derivative of $f$ at $a$. Then which are correct?

1. $(Df)(a)h=2ah$, where $a=a_{1}+ia_{2}$ & $h=h_{1}+ih_{2}.$
2. $(Df)(a)=2\begin{bmatrix}a_{1} & -a_{2} \\ a_{2} & a_{1}\end{bmatrix}$.
3. $f$  is one-one.
4. For any $a\in \mathbb R^{n}\setminus \{(0,0)\}$, $f$ is one-one on some nbd. of $a$.

We know that, $(Df)(a)=\bigtriangledown f(a).$ So, option (2) is correct. But, how option (a) is correct ? Also the others are true or not?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18598/discussion-on-question-by-panja-s-function-from-mathbb-r2-to-mathbb-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is not one-one, since for $z_1=1+i$ and $z_2=-1-i$, we get $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$ but $z_1\neq z_2$.

Comment: OK.Option (3) is wrong. But the others?